# Loading Symbols for crystaldecisions.xxxxxxxxxxx.dll

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am creating a VB.net application that access database in SQL . To print the data I made several Crystal reports and open them from within my application by referencing the 
    Crystaldecision.crystalreports.engine 
    Crystaldecision.shared
    Crystaldecision.windows.forms

It worked fine for several months. now Started giving me an error message. so I removed the references and tried adding them again and every time I add one I get the message:
Loading Symbols for Crystaldecision.crystalreports.engine.dll 
Loading Symbols for Crystaldecision.windows.forms.dll

and it takes forever to respond and the program freezes to the point that I have to use task manager to end it.

Any advice?

Comment: What error message did you start getting originally?

Comment: FYI, "Loading Symbols for any.arbitrary.dll" is not an error.